# I want to use bcrypt.compare together with mongoose/mongo enginee search

Tags: mongodb, encryption, mongoose, bcrypt, cryptojs

Consider this code:

```
const hashPassword = function(plainText) {
  return crypto
    .createHmac(process.env.Secret_hash_Password, "secret key")
    .update(plainText)
    .digest("hex");
};
```

As you may have noticed, this is a simple hashing function using `crypto`.

Now consider this code excerpt:

```
bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, isMatch) => {....}
```

As you may have noticed, this is a simple comparing hashing function using `bcryptjs`.

As I believe everyone will agree, *the second is most secure*.

Now consider the problem:

*I have a key to store on mongo, and this key is a sensitive information, as so, I have decided to hash it as so no one can decrypt it.* This key is used to make mongo searches, this an information that just the user has, a sort of password.

**Solution**: use the first code, as so nonetheless you cannot decrypt, you can get the same result of hashing if the input is the same.

**Problem**: my solution is using a tecnique that is well-known to be easily hacked, someone that somehow had access to the server just need to enter several inputs and once they get the same output, they got it! this is a well-known flaw of my solution.

**Desired solution**: use the second code with mongo.

**Discussion**: I could simply get all the database information with `find({})`, and apply say `ForEach` and `bcrypt.compare`, nonetheless, I know from my studies that mongo is optimized for search, e.g. they use indexes. It would be nice to be able to pass the `bcrypt.compare` as a **customized function** to mongo search enginee.

It was suggested "Increase the bcrypt salt rounds.": **I cannot use salt** since that would change the key and whenever I will need to compare, it will change. `bcrypt.compare`exists to overcome that, but mongo/mongoose queries does not have such internal enginee. 
 [image]

What  I have in my head, in pseudocode:

```
Model.findOne({bcrypt.compare (internalID, internalID')}) //return when true
```

Where: bcrypt.compare (internalID, internalID') would be a sort of callback function, on each search, mongo would use this function with `internalID'`, the current `internalID`  under comparison, and return the document that produces true.

***Any suggestion, comment, or anything?***

PS. I am using mongoose.

Comment: > Your concern: Problem: my solution is using a technique that is well-known to be easily hacked, someone just needs to enter several inputs and once they get the same output, they got it! this is a well-known flaw in my solution. > Potential Solution: Increase the bcrypt salt rounds.

Comment: That is the problem: **I cannot use salt** since in that case I will not have a key that is the same. Whenever I use `find()`, or any other function, I need to provide a key that is equal the one in the database: `bcrypt.compare` does not require to know the key, but mongo/mongoose related queries require. Imagine everytime I want to look for the id it is changed? it does not work. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Can you show us you're schema?

Comment: Hey there, the code is pretty big, including the schemas, it will just create problem if I add the code. I will see if I post a short version, but I believe what I have said is enough. My code works, I just want to improve.

Comment: is the key you're trying to store along with user data in mongo some sort of session key (since it's coming from client) ? or is it some sort of password for user to access their data stored in some other collection?

Comment: it is the id of the document, but the id is a number that cannot be seen by people, except the one that submitted: it is a patient identification, just the doctor can see it. It is a sort of password and I can compare using `bcrypt.compare`, put my point is: I want to avoid bring documents from a `find({})` to compare one by one and return a match, like we do with password, but password is just one user, imagine 1.000, it may be even fast, but maybe there is a better way to solve that.

Comment: So, to summarise, you are hashing _id of the user document, and returning that from client and want to un-hash that before querying the database again using your pseudo-code- Model.findOne({bcrypt.compare (internalID, internalID')}) //return when true
?

Comment: Nope, no unhashing, that is the point, I want to make sure it is impossible, or close to it, to unhash. It is not the _id, it is the patient id, entered by the doctor, I have not idea how it looks like, and I cannot know that, just that it is a string.

Comment: Now: I am storing a hashed id, but I want to increase the security, by using salt, but if I use salt, I cannot longer just give it to mongo after hashing since it will change everytime the user enter the same key, that is the point of `bcrypt.compare`, to save you the work of comparing something difficult to compare; and I want to make use of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what i understand, you don't ever want anyone to know the patient ids (non -discover-able from real life patient-ids), even the database admin (and of course hackers).
I think you design is a bit messed up. 
Firstly - indexes use B tree data structure for faster lookup so you have to provide exact string for lookup and by your condition of un-hash-able ids, indexes won't work. So you'll have to iterate over every patient id by that doctor and compare to get true result, which is pretty compute- extensive and frankly bad design.
There are multiple ways to approach to approaching this problem- depending upon your level of trust and paranoia.

I think using cryptojs is the correct solution. Now you have to add some randomness to the key/solution. Basically you hash the id with cryptojs, but instead of supplying the key yourself, you could take the secret key from doctor itself then hash every id with that key. Now you will have to unhash and hash every patient id everytime doctor changes secret key (using some sort of message queue).
You could also hash the secret key entered by doctor before saving and will have to unhash everytime (twice!) doctor wants to lookup by patientId.

Depending upon the number of users you expect your application to serve, if number is low enough- my solution would work. But too many users, you'd have to increase compute resources and probably invest in some security measures instead of my overkill solution. Why'd you be losing secret key to hackers anyway?

Good luck.

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the answer. I believe my current solution is good enough, I was just curious to see if my second guess could work, it seems not. My current system is a prototype, I have a "boss" that is somehow paranoid, as so, I would like to make sure he has no reason to complain regarding my design. I believe I have a good solution now. My concern is if someone, even an admin, could have access to that. There are tough laws, and with reasons, to protect patients, and trust is something that once is  broken, it is hard to get back. Thus, our users should trust the system!

Comment: ", you could take the secret key from doctor itself then hash every id with that key.." I like this :)